# SSRS in .Net Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

We have a C# Windows Application.

We also have SSRS reports.

Can we deploy the application so that the reports are rendered on the local machine rather than using a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You need to set the ReportViewer control to render the reports in local processing mode.
You will need to use the WinForm version of the reportviewer control to accomplish this.

To set the ReportViewer to accept local data sources, you can set the ReportViewer.ProcessingMode property to local.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't know what you are asking me.

Comment: the link that you posted with More Info takes me to a news story about Virgin Galactic space flight. (http://newslite.tv/2010/03/23/virgin-galactic-spaceship-comp.html)